# Cron task python script not working

Tags: python, cron, cron-task

I have a python script I want to fire off every night at midnight. I'm using cron scheduler right now to do so, however, I can't figure out why it's not working. For now, I've been using close times (within the next minute or so) to test the cronjob, but I will ultimately want it to work for midnight.

Here is what I put in my crontab file (to run for 2:43pm), hosted on my ubuntu machine:

```
43 14 * * * root /home/grantmcgovern/Developer/Projects/StudyBug/Main.py
```

I even put the:

```
#!user/bin/python
```

on top of all the .py files.

I also did:

```
chmod +x "scriptname".py
```

For each of the .py files and still no luck. Am I missing something blatantly obvious? I should note, this is my first time playing with cron tasks.

Comment: The shebang line (the first line in the Python scripts) should look like `#!/usr/bin/python`, not `#!user/bin/python`.

Comment: @bdesham Thanks for that catch, still no luck though.

Comment: As an alternative to #!/usr/bin/python ... #!/usr/bin/env python

Comment: @clutton I tried that, unfortunately that did not work either

Comment: Try 0 0 * * * root /home/grantmcgovern/Developer/Projects/StudyBug/Main.py if you want to run it at midnight.

Comment: Does your syslog show that the cron triggered?

Comment: you can log the execution by adding `> /tmp/mycronlog.log` at the end making it `43 14 * * * root /home/grantmcgovern/Developer/Projects/StudyBug/Main.py > /tmp/mycronlog.log`. What does the log say?

Comment: @evading Nothing is in the log

Comment: @carbon_ghost - make sure the log is a writeable file in a writeable directory (i.e. you have permissions to run it). Also, in your SSH (if you have access to it), can you run the same command (minus the cron)?

Comment: Sorry, you might need to pipe stderr to stdout allso. Try `43 14 * * * root /home/grantmcgovern/Developer/Projects/StudyBug/Main.py > /tmp/mycronlog.log 2>&1` Note the last bit. [edit] also, do what @Duniyadnd says :)

Comment: @evading the thing is though, I wouldn't even need the log file to know if it's running successfully. I'm using selenium, a python web driver library, that physically opens Firefox every time the script is run so I would know if it was running that way.

Comment: After the most recent execution, this is the output I got in the log: /bin/sh: 1: root: not found

Comment: @carbon_ghost Maybe so, but the log file might tell you where the script crashes.

Comment: That is telling you that you are trying to run a program named root.

Comment: @carbon_ghost if my answer below helped you, please mark it as accepted :)

Answer (score 2):

From your current crontab file, you're basically running `root /home/grantmcgovern/Developer/Projects/StudyBug/Main.py` every time.

If you want to run it as root, use `sudo crontab -e` and put `43 14 * * * /usr/bin/python /home/grantmcgovern/Developer/Projects/StudyBug/Main.py` instead.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is looking for the command "root" so the syntax is wrong, so it should be this...

43 14 * * * /home/grantmcgovern/Developer/Projects/StudyBug/Main.py

If you need it to run as root then I think you can use su like this:

43 14 * * * su root -c "/home/grantmcgovern/Developer/Projects/StudyBug/Main.py"

If you add it to the system crontab then I think it will anyway.